# How can I create a nested map in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a nested map in dart :

```dart
static Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>> items = new Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>>();
```

and add values to this map when pressing a button :

```dart
Mainclass.items.addAll({
    "keyname" : {
        "firestvalue": 100, // cghange every press
        "secondvalue": 100 // cghange every press
    }
});
```

This is not working, it everytime shows length 1 :

```dart
print("length" + account.items.length.toString());
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: It should be length 1, since there is only one key/value pair ("keyname": ...) in items. What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an implementation how you can do
you can make function addValuesToMap()

```
Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>> items = {};

  void addValuesToMap() {
    String keyName = 'keyname';
    int firstValue = 100;
    int secondValue = 100;

    setState(() {
      items[keyName] = {
        'firstvalue': firstValue,
        'secondvalue': secondValue,
      };
    });
  }
```

then this function you can call in elevated button

```
ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        addValuesToMap();
      },
      child: Text('Add Values'),
    )
```

Comment: sorry i can't items[keyName]   because if we  have duplicated will replace

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you expect to happen. However, if you want to dump values into a map of map, you want to maintain a key/index for each inner map you add.

```
Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>> items = {};

  void addValuesToMap() {
    String keyName = 'keyname';
    int firstValue = 100;
    int secondValue = 100;

    setState(() {
      items["${items.length}"] = {
        keyname: {
            "firestvalue": firstValue, // change every press
            "secondvalue": secondValue // change every press
         }
       };
    });
  }
```

You can call the `addValuesToMap()` function from the onpressed of a button.